# Is there anyway to log the error without breaking a loop?

Tags: r, logging, message, break

I am using a loop to process a bunch of files, some of which could be poorly formatted, and cause error.
for example

> for (i in 1:100)
>
> ```
> file_processor(file[i])
> ```

if the 50th file is in unexpected format, and cause an error, is there any way to put the error in a log file, and keep the loop running till the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a try/catch INSIDE the loop.  Catch the exception, LOG IT, and then do not (re) throw it.  Put a good comment on why you are choosing to swallow the exception.  Swallowing exceptions should be used very sparingly.

Comment: +1 for the best practices, but the answer could use some more detail. Using `try` correctly in `R` is not trivial